# How do I setup a UBI8 container to compile PDF documents via sphinx?

Tags: rhel, docker

I see that there is a debian based image that can do this here (https://hub.docker.com/r/sphinxdoc/sphinx-latexpdf), but I need to base my solution on Red Hat UBI 8 container image. What packages do I need to install in order for this to function on that platform? (I will be on a RHEL subscribed machine when building.)

I expect to mount a volume with my documentation in Restructured Text format and want the container to provide HTML and PDF output via Sphinx the same way that the linked sphinxdoc/sphinx-latexpdf document does.

Answer (score 0):

The various requirements appear to be spread across the CodeReady, AppStream and Epel repos. You'll need to setup all those and then it appears that installing just about every `texlive-*` package is needed. I put the list of those in texlive-requirements.txt. Then I created this Dockerfile and built it. I also assume you'll have some python requirements to put into pip-requirements.txt.

```
FROM ubi8
WORKDIR /docs

# Setup Extra RPM repositories
# CodeReady Builder is an EPEL dependency and has several texlive-* packages
# Epel is a dependency of latexmk
RUN yum -y update \
  && yum -y install yum-utils \
  && yum-config-manager --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms \
  && rpm --import http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8 \
  && yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

# Fill texlive-requirements.txt with all the packages in 
# `yum list available|grep texlive` as run from a UBI8 container with 
# the above repos provided
ARG deps="ImageMagick graphviz make wget enchant curl python3-pip latexmk"
ADD texlive-requirements.txt /tmp/yum.txt
RUN yum install -y $deps $(cat /tmp/yum.txt) && \
    yum clean all

# For whatever python dependencies, put them in pip-requirements.txt
ADD pip-requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

This should work just like the [image at docker hub that sphinx provides](https://hub.docker.com/r/sphinxdoc/sphinx-latexpdf) including the volume mount and supporting both HTML and LatexPDF builds.